# Dividing balls into boxes with capacity limits

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

**Problem:**

In how many ways can you divide $13$ identical balls into $3$ different boxes
$k_1$, $k_2$, $k_3$, such that $k_1$ contains no more than $5$ balls, $k_2$ contains no more than $6$ balls and $k_3$ contains no more than $4$ balls?

**My idea:**

So my idea is to use the following theorem:
"There are $C(n+r-1,r)$ r-combinations from a set with $n$ elements when repetition of elements is allowed." But I'm not sure.

Any great hints would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. Rather than grabbing a theorem to try, think about actually distributing the balls. How would you systematically count the possibilities for a smaller problem - say $5$ with limits $2$, $3$ abd $4$?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle

Comment: The theorem you cited is useful, but you then have to take into account the three restrictions you mentioned.   Please edit your question to show us what you have attempted and indicate where you are stuck.

Comment: You can accept an answer which suits the question according to your requirements if all your doubts have been cleared by checking the ✓ mark. If you have any other doubts please share

Answer (score 5):

$\mathbf {\text {Method 2 (Must see)} }$

Define $k_1=5-a$ , $k_2=6-b$ and $k_3=4-c$

Hence we get $$a+b+c=2$$
And we need non negative integral solutions of this equation which are $$\binom {4}{2}=6$$

Luckily this preserves non negativity of $k_1$,$k_2$ and $k_3$

Comment: Nice shortcut (+1)

Comment: @true blue anil Thanks. :-)

Answer (score 2):

The answer can simply be given using generating functions. We simply need to calculate the coefficient of $x^{13}$in the expansion of $$(1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4)(1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5)(1+x+x^2+x^3+x^6)$$
$$=\frac {(1-x^5)}{(1-x)}\cdot  \frac {(1-x^6)}{(1-x)}\cdot  \frac {(1-x^7)}{(1-x)}$$

$$=\frac {1-x^5-x^6-x^7+x^{11}+x^{13}+x^{12}-x^{18}}{(1-x)^3}$$

Hence the answer simply goes as $$\binom {15}{13} -\binom {10}{8}- \binom {9}{7}-\binom {8}{6}+\binom {4}{2}+1+\binom {3}{1}=6$$

Comment: How are you reading off those binomial coefficients?

Comment: @Peter Taylor Use the negative binomial series for the denominator to get that coefficients. For eg. We have $-x^5$ in the numerator hence we need the coefficient of $x^8$ from $(1-x)^{-3}$ which is simply $\binom {10}{8}$. For more information on negative binomial power series refer to. 
  http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NegativeBinomialSeries.html

Answer (score 0):

To show the working behind the generating function approach:

A binomial expansion of $(1-x)^{-n}$ gives $$(1-x)^{-n} = 1 + (-n)(-x) + \frac{(-n)(-n-1)}{2!} (-n)^2 + \frac{(-n)(-n-1)(-n-2)}{3!} (-n)^3 + \cdots \\
= \sum_{i\ge 0}\frac{(-1)^i (-n)^\underline{i}}{i!}x^i \\
= \sum_{i\ge 0}\frac{n^\overline{\,i\,}}{i!}x^i \\
= \sum_{i \ge 0}\binom{n+i-1}{i}x^i \\
= \sum_{i \ge 0}\binom{n+i-1}{n-1}x^i$$

Then $$[x^k] \frac{\sum_{j\ge 0} a_j x^j}{(1-x)^n} = \sum_{j\ge 0} [x^k] \frac{a_j x^j}{(1-x)^n} = \sum_{j\ge 0} a_j [x^{k-j}] (1-x)^{-n} = \sum_{j\ge 0} a_j \binom{n+k-j-1}{n-1}$$

---

Now we can apply that to your problem as outlined in Manthanein's first answer: by considering the three boxes we're looking for the coefficient of $x^{13}$ in $$\frac {(1-x^6)(1-x^7)(1-x^5)}{(1-x)^3} = \frac{1-x^5-x^6-x^7+x^{11}+x^{12}+x^{13}-x^{18}}{(1-x)^3}$$

So applying the lemma with $n=3$, $k=13$ we get $$\binom{15-0}{2}-\binom{15-5}{2}-\binom{15-6}{2}-\cdots-\binom{15-18}{2}$$
The last term is zero, and the rest give $$\frac{15\times14 - 10\times9 -9\times8 - 8\times7 + 4\times3 + 3\times2 + 2\times1}{2}\\
= \frac{210-90-72-56+12+6+2}{2} = 6$$